# How to sleep/delayed execution in an asynchronous framework based on Java's Executors

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, delayed-execution

I have an existing framework which is based on ThreadPools and Java `Executor`/`ExecutorService`, but not `ScheduledExecutorService`. The framework is heavily based on asynchronous execution and `Future` to send work to a queue of items, then being processed by only a few threads, while still supporting a large number of operations per timeframe.

I have a certain functionality where I need to retry the work after waiting a bit, as it is likely that it will work after a short amount of time (a few seconds), but it is obviously discouraged to use Thread.sleep() in such a framework as it will use up one of the few threads for the full time of waiting.

Ideally I would use a `ScheduledExecutorService` to not block a thread while waiting, but in this case I am bound to what the framework offers, so I am stuck with an Executor service.

I also thought about queueing the request myself and repeatedly sending off new futures, but I think this will consume a lot of CPU as it would be kind of an elaborate busy loop until the time has elapsed.

Is there a better way via some Java functionality to delay work in such a situation without using up a thread?

Comment: What do you mean you are "bound to what the framework offers"? Does that mean you can't create new threads? That you can't add any "static" (singleton or whatever long-lived) resource? Also, helping with your question would be much easier (to the point that someone will actually want to help!) if you disclose what framework you are using and include some code. :-)

Comment: I would like to not create new threads on my own. "Framework" here is actually Elasticsearch Java Client API, which uses Thread Pools internally and I want to enhance it's functionality with retries. I don't have actual code to show, the pieces that I have don't add much to the question...

Comment: Couldn't you put a `ScheduledExecutorService` in front that would submit the tasks to the framework's executor at scheduled time?

Comment: Thanks, I solved it somehow differently in the meantime and moved on...